# Error executing “PutObject” on AWS

Tags: laravel-5, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am trying to read .png file from storage path of laravel and upload the same into amazon s3, but i'm getting this below issue:

> {
>       "code": 422,
>       "status": "error",
>       "data": {
>           "exception": "Error executing \"PutObject\" on \"https://s3.amazonaws.com/mrxmms/123/12345_ach.png\"; AWS HTTP error:
>   count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements
>   Countable"
>       },
>       "message": "Unprocessable Entity" }

Here is my sample code:

> $dir = storage_path('uploads');   $image_val = $dir. '/'
>   ."product.png";
>
> $image_load =
>   Storage::disk('s3')->put("123/12345.png",file_get_contents($image_val));

Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

This issue hit me recently when using Guzzle in version 6.2.1 and AWS SDK in version 3.*
Updating Guzzle to 6.3.* solved the issue for me.

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:6.3.*
```

Hope that helps.